# How can you order a free group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, order-theory, free-groups, ordered-groups

A **left order** on a (discrete) group $G$ is a total order on $G$ satisfying $\forall g,h,k \in G: g < h \implies kg < kh$. A **right order** is defined symmetrically, and a **biorder** is an order that is both at once. An order is **scattered** if it has no densely ordered subset of cardinality at least two, where a set $S$ is **densely ordered** if $a, c \in S \wedge a \neq c \implies \exists b \in S: a < b < c$.

I'm interested in order types of left orders (and biorders, why not). It's easy to show that left orders on the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ all have order type $\mathbb{Z}$, and on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ there are two constructions of left orders, and as far as I can tell one gives order type $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in lex order (so scattered), and the other orders are dense (so not scattered).

Let $F_2$ be the free nonabelian group on two generators.

> Does $F_2$ admit a scattered left order?
>
> Does $F_2$ admit a scattered biorder?

I had an awesome application for this, but I broke it already. Now I'm just curious. I don't actually know what you get from the Magnus embedding $a \mapsto 1+a$, I admit I was too lazy (or scared?) to even give it real thought, and I did not notice a statement in the literature.

More generally, one may ask:

> What are the order-types of left orders on $F_2$?
>
> What are the order-types of biorders on $F_2$?

More generally, I'm interested in information on order types of orders on any torsion-free groups, there's plenty of literature on orders but I haven't seen much about order types.

Comment: Weaker than your first question, but $F_2$ acts faithfully on a scattered left order. Indeed, for each quotient by a term of the lower central series one get such a (non-faithful) action, and then one can concatenate.

Comment: Does everything? Is there a simple torsion-free non-orderable group?

Comment: Erm wait, dyadic rationals.

Comment: Don't understand your last 2 questions. You're using "simple" in the meaning "non-complicated"? Anyway every torsion-free abelian group is orderable. Nevertheless I agree that for $p\ge 2$ $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]$ (and hence $BS(1,p)$) cannot act faithfully on any scattered totally ordered space.

Comment: I mean simple in the usual sense. With the first question I meant, does everything act on a scattered left order? If yes, then your observation is not very interesting. With the second question, I figured if you have a simple torsion-free non-orderable group, then that will be a counterexample. But then I realized $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is an easier example. I agree you can also f.g.ify it.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first clarify the relationship between scattered, discrete, and dense orders. The last two notions are standard in the theory of ordered groups.

An order (left or two-sided) is discrete if there exists a smallest (necessarily unique) positive element. If such an element does not exist, the order is called dense.

We claim that no dense order (left or two-sided) is scattered. Moreover, we claim that, if the order is dense, then the entire group is a densely ordered set. Indeed, if $a < b$ then $e < a^{-1}b$ and, since the order is dense, there exists $c$ such that $e < c < a^{-1}b$ and we obtain $a < ac < b$.

On the other hand, discrete orders are not necessarily scattered. For instance the lexicographic bi-order on $\mathbb{Z} \times F_2$, with any bi-order on $F_2$, is discrete with smallest element $(1,e)$, but there are densely ordered subsets, namely the copy of $F_2$.

---

Going back to the posed question, since free groups of rank > 1 do not admit discrete bi-orders (in fact, no centerless group admits a discrete bi-order) they do not admit scattered bi-orders.

On the other hand, there are discrete left-orders on free groups of rank > 1, and, therefore, the question is more interesting there.

The claim that centerless groups do not admit discrete bi-orders follows from Theorem 2.1 in the paper cited below, while the claim that free groups admit discrete orders (that are, moreover Conradian) is Corollary 3.6 in the same paper.

*Linnell, Peter A.; Rhemtulla, Akbar; Rolfsen, Dale P. O.*, [**Discretely ordered groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/ant.2009.3.797), Algebra Number Theory 3, No. 7, 797-807 (2009). [ZBL1229.06008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1229.06008).

Comment: Very nice! Can you give a reference for the last two paragraphs?

Comment: I believe you also give a complete answer to the fourth question, as there is a unique dense countable total order without endpoints.

Comment: Added a reference.

Comment: By the way, as I recall, the Magnus embedding order is one of those that can be obtained from the lower central series.